Correctly understand the implication of approximation ratio for the set cover problem?
I am currently reading this wikipedia article about the set cover problem and it said here that "it cannot be approximated to $\left[ {1 - o\left( 1 \right)} \right]\ln \left( n \right)$ unless $P=NP$".
I am not sure if my understanding of this issue is correct or not.
So if the approximation ratio is $\frac{{{c^{Approx}}}}{{{c^*}}} = \left[ {1 - o\left( 1 \right)} \right]\ln \left( n \right)$ and we cannot do better than this in polynomial time then why does there is a case when the solution from the greedy method is the same as the global optimal solution.
It seems to me that if the solution from the greedy method is the same as the global optimal solution then this would imply that $\frac{{{c^{Approx}}}}{{{c^*}}} = 1$ which does not make any sense for NP-hard problem.
Would you kindly help me to realize the flaw of my logic. My guess is that the approximation ratio should be in expectation over all se cover instances $E\left[ {\frac{{{c^{Approx}}}}{{{c^*}}}} \right] \le \left[ {1 - o\left( 1 \right)} \right]\ln \left( n \right)$ instead of just plain $\frac{{{c^{Approx}}}}{{{c^*}}} = \left[ {1 - o\left( 1 \right)} \right]\ln \left( n \right)$
Thank you for your enthusiasm !

I think you may be confusing "cannot approximate all instances unless $P=NP$" with "cannot approximate any instance unless $P=NP$". The statements in the Wikipedia entry should be interpreted as saying that set covering problems cannot be solved to a certain guaranteed accuracy in polynomial time (meaning that you can be sure a method gets you that close to an optimal solution on every problem instance in polynomial time) unless $P=NP.$ Nothing stops you from getting lucky on a particular instance of the problem.

Oh can you elaborate more. Now I am completely confusing :(

You linked a video from a course lecture. To what specific part of the video are you referring?

The final result of the greedy method is $x_2=1$ and $x_4=1$ and the rest of $x_i=0$ .When I use a global solver like Mathematica, it also output the same result. This make me confusing because I think that greedy can never output a good result

Greedy can find a "good" solution (fairly frequently) and an optimal solution (sometimes). This is largely a matter of luck. What it cannot do is guarantee an optimal solution.

Oh can you make an official answer for this question to help me get over my confusion ?

I amended my answer.

But what does this little o(1) even means ?
